# Posting to Facebook wall in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

I'm using [this wrapper](https://github.com/phildow/SPFacebookClient) to try to post an image with a caption to the user's wall:

I've gotten it to post to the photo album with the following code, but I can't figure out how to make it post to the user's wall.

```
UIImage *img = [logo getMyLogoImage];        
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is a caption! Do you know this logo?",@"message",img,@"picture",nil];
[[SPFacebookClient_MyApp sharedClient] requestWithParams:params completionHandler:^(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error){}];
```

I can see that using the regular Facebook sdk, I could call this to post to the wall:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/Photos"
          parameters:params
          HTTPMethod:@"POST"
          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){[self showAlert:@"Photo Post" result:result error:error];}];
```

I would really love to figure out how to make that happen with the wrapper though, since it makes managing sessions and general setup much easier and cleaner. Can anyone explain what I would have to change or add to make this work?

Comment: To post to the user's wall you should compose a request with the string `@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"`

Comment: Please specify which permissions that you have setted ?

Comment: Aprit, I've requested "offline_access" and "publish_stream" as permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as below and try.

```
UIImage *img = [logo getMyLogoImage];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is a caption! Do you know this logo?",@"message",img,@"picture",nil];    
[[SPExampleFacebookClient sharedClient] requestWithName:@"stream.publish" params:params method:@"POST" completionHandler:^(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: I get an error in the log: "Cannot use GET to upload a file". Debugging, I can see that within the library, [Facebook requestWithParams] is always forcing GET.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried it and got a new error. The result in the completion handler is an HTML page saying "Sorry, something went wrong". Could it be that this wrapper is using old SDK components? Strange that it would read okay.

Comment: The more I look at this, I'm pretty sure this wrapper is just using out of date stuff. I'll see if I can write my own using the current version of the SDK.